# How to add linux-rt and linux-rt-lts to bootloader on Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, boot-loader, systemd-boot

Below is the list of linux packages installed on my Arch system.

```bash
$ pacman -Qsq 'linux' | grep -E '^linux*'
linux
linux-api-headers
linux-firmware
linux-hardened
linux-hardened-headers
linux-headers
linux-lts
linux-lts-headers
linux-rt
linux-rt-headers
linux-rt-lts
linux-rt-lts-headers
linux-zen
linux-zen-headers
```

As you can see the kernels installed are `linux`, `linux-hardened`, `linux-lts`, `linux-rt`, `linux-rt-lts` and `linux-zen`. However when I turn on the computer I only see eight entries - `linux`, `linux-hardened`, `linux-lts`, `linux-zen` and their fallbacks. How can I add entries so that I can try out `linux-rt` and `linux-rt-lts`? My bootloader is `systemd-boot`.

Comment: Did you try to follow the steps described here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-boot ?